# Visual Studio 2013 resize window shortcut hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to make a hotkey to resize the width of the current editor window in VS2013?

I do pretty much everything entirely through hotkeys EXCEPT resizing my windows. Most often I have 2 or 3 editors open in the same window vertically so each one is relatively narrow. Switching between the windows is easy with Ctrl + Tab but I really wish I could press a hotkey with left/right arrows to increase/decrease width of the current editor.

EDIT: Or at least go full screen into the current window temporarily. This is not the same as going full screen normally with Shift + Alt + Enter since that full screens all 3 windows still seperated.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps not quite what you want but VS has a shortcut for "Window.Float".

`Options > Keyboard > Window.Float`

Assign a shortcut for it (I've assigned `Ctrl + W, Down Arrow`)

When you float the window, you can snap it using the Windows shortcut of WinKey + Arrows.

`WinKey + Left` snaps the window to the next left-available position.

`WinKey + Right` snaps the window to the next right-available position.

`WinKey + Up` maximises.

`WinKey + Down` minimises.

Comment: Cool, this will work actually but is there a way to snap the window back into VS?

Comment: Yup, it's the (very helpfully named /s) "Window.MoveToMainDocumentGroup" shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to keep the tool windows "Solution exp, Team exp, .." as hidden,
and then using their shortcuts to show them again. When you are done press "Alt + _" for the alt-space menu.

For example, using the default settings, I have solution explorer hidden.
My use flow is:

1. Ctrl+p ctrl+p      [Show the solution explorer window]
2. Use the keyboard to navigate or skip #1 and press "Ctrl+;" to search
3. When I'm done, press "esc" to hide it
   or for windows where I want it to stay open: "Alt+_" then press "k" for dock